# Sort column by manual order in SAS

Tags: sorting, sas

data `have`

```
Game  col2 col3 col4 ..

ABC
AZA
CGG
EDD
```

I need sort data `HAVE` by `Game`. But for output dataset `WANT`, the order should always be

```
Game  col2 col3 col4 ..

AZA
ABC
EDD
CGG
```

How to achieve this in SAS? Also, the required order stored in an external file. If the required order changes, I need to adjust my code. So I want an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an informat as per the below and sort on the resulting values.

```
PROC FORMAT;
INVALUE SEX
'AZA' = 1
'ABC' = 2
'EDD' = 3
'CGG' = 4
;
RUN;

DATA HAVE;
TEST = "CGG";
OUTPUT;
TEST = "EDD";
OUTPUT;
TEST = "AZA";
OUTPUT;
RUN;

DATA WANT;
    SET HAVE;
    TEST2 = INPUT(TEST,SEX.);
RUN;

PROC SORT DATA = WANT;
BY TEST2;
RUN;
```